# How to get text from clipboard in swift 4

Tags: ios, swift

I don't want to write the link " https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask" as shown in this line. I want url to receive the last copied URL from clipboard, what should I add?

```
let url = URL(string: "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask")
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Copy**

```
let url = URL(string: "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask")
UIPasteboard.general.string = url
```

**Paste**

```
if let url = UIPasteboard.general.string {
        url = url
}
```

Comment: Do not use the same name for the url in the clipboard and the variable you are copying the url into

Comment: @Dimitrie-TomaFurdui What where you doing on stackoverflow a 24th of december at 20:36 ?? haha

Comment: @Josh What was I doing?